# find an object's property and get its value - C#

Tags: c#

say there is a class like

```
class phones
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
List<phones> myList = GetData();
//list is filled with objects
```

Now, I know the Id and the exact name of the object's property and want to get the value from the matching object.

```
private string GetValue(int pid, string featurename)
{
  string val = "";
 foreach(phones obj in myList)
  {
   if(obj.Id == pid)
    {
      //if featurename is 'Name', it should be
      //val = obj.Name;

      //if featurename is 'Price', it should return
      //val = obj.Price;
      break;
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

Is this possible. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 Phones phones= new Phones();          
 string returnValue = phones.GetType().GetProperty(featureName).GetValue(phones, null).ToString();
```

Also, remember to add validation for input `featureName` and error handling.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
 foreach(phones obj in myList)
  {
   if(obj.Id == pid)
    {
      if (featurename == "Name")
      {
         return obj.Name;
      }
      else if (featurename == "Price")
      {
         return obj.Price.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
         return string.Empty;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Property with given featurename and use it
you could use lambda expression like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

or

Use [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(ClassName).GetProperties())
{
    string propertyName = p.Name;
    //....
}
```